# DirectX12 Frame Resources

Tags: directx-12

I am currently working on a project where I want to have UI, I have created a UI Manager class and inside it I create the appropriate geometry , shaders, layouts and then within my main class I can call update and Draw on this Manager class

My question is following Frank Luna's book a frame resources is created within the main class and it holds all items and all materials.... I obviously want my UI Manager class to handle everything so do I need to have a seperate frame resource within my UI Manager class which I call update on , or do I have to pass all the items created back to main class and add them to that frame resource?

Hopefully this makes sense but if needed I could show some code to explain what I mean

Thanks

Comment: Try doing this with DirectX 11 first. If you are new to Direct3D, you shouldn't be using DIrect3D 12.

Comment: I am familiar with Directx11 i spent last two years using that so i am ready for directx just not fully sure on a few of the new things...however it was pointed out to me if i redesign my classes it will be alot neater and also answers my question

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [DeviceResources](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/DeviceResources) abstraction for some ideas.

Comment: not heard of that and when i searched for it nothing was coming up, but i got the help i needed and it all works now :) its good when you sit down with some paper and design the classes before trying to jump in and build it lol